# Reset offset, onTapGesture works, but onRotated does not work, why?

Tags: rotation, swiftui

I want the view containing 2 rectangles floating in the bottom of the screen, whatever the orientation is portrait or landscape.

code is a test, when orientationDidChangeNotification happened, I Found UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait and UIScreen.main.bounds.height often have wrong value, why?

Anyway, test code is just reset offset = 0 in onRotated(). but it doesn't work; otherwise onTapGesture works fine.

Q1: Is it a wrong way for SwiftUI? SceneDelegate.orientationDidChangeNotification -> contentView.onRotated()?

Q2: why do UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait and UIScreen.main.bounds.height often have wrong value?

Q3: How to let a view float at the bottom of screen in both portrait and landscape?

```
let height: CGFloat = 100

struct TestView: View {
    @State var offset = (UIScreen.main.bounds.height - height) / 2

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("+")
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle().fill(Color.blue)
                Rectangle().fill(Color.red)
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: height)
            .offset(y: offset)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.offset = 0
            }
        }
    }

    func onRotated() {
//        let isPortrait =  UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
        offset = 0//(UIScreen.main.bounds.height - height) / 2
//        print("\(isPortrait), screen height = \(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)")
    }
}

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let contentView = TestView()
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
                contentView.onRotated()
            }

            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`contentView` is not a reference, it is a value, so you call `.onRotated` on own copy of `contentView` value that lives only within callback

```
    let contentView = TestView() 
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
            contentView.onRotated() // local copy!!!
        }
```

instead create listener for notification publisher inside TestView, so it can change self internally.

Moreover, it is not clear the intention but SwiftUI gives possibility to track size classes via `EnvironmentValues.horizontalSizeClass` and `EnvironmentValues.verticalSizeClass` which are automatically changed on device orientation, so it is possible to make your view layout depending on those environment values even w/o notification.

[See here good example on how to use size classes](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/changing-a-views-layout-in-response-to-size-classes)

Comment: contentView is not a reference, this is the key! I understand. so My solution is totally wrong!
My intent is clear, How to let a view float at the bottom of screen in both portrait and landscape? I dont think it works using size classes.

Comment: another question, How can I get ContentView from SceneDelegate and perform contentView.onRotated()?

Comment: @foolbear, you can't. In SwiftUI you operate with model, depending on which state view is changed. Model changed - view reacts, no messages.